# japplet open second window

Tags: applet

is it possible to open a new window from a japplet? right now i'm using getAppletContext().showDocument() to open a document, but it closes my applet. anyone know how to open a second window without interfering with the applet?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the version that takes a target as well and pass "_blank" as the target:

```
getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL("http://www.google.com"), "_blank");
```